# What does this syntax mean JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, regex

I was going through some open source codes when I stumbled upon this library : [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he/).

In the source code written in javascript it has statements like this:

```
var regexInvalidRawCodePoint = /<%= regexInvalidRawCodePoints %>/;
```

I can't figure out what it means. Tried googling it too.

Btw it's not standard regex. The script is **not trying to match regexInvalidRawCodePoint**.

Comment: it finds the pattern between the slashes, being `<%= regexInvalidRawCodePoints %>`. There are not any wildcards, so it's looking for that specific string.

Comment: This is the regex pattern to match the given string between / /

Comment: It doesn't make sense. If you read the source code. file -> src/he.js

Comment: It's a Regular Expression literal. You might like to read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `package.json` you have a build script:

`"build": "grunt build"`

This build script will create the `he.js` file out of the `src/he.js` file.

In the build process the line:

```
var regexInvalidRawCodePoint = /<%= regexInvalidRawCodePoints %>/;
```

will become

```
var regexInvalidRawCodePoint = /[\0-\x08\x0B\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\uFDD0-\uFDEF\uFFFE\uFFFF]|[\uD83F\uD87F\uD8BF\uD8FF\uD93F\uD97F\uD9BF\uD9FF\uDA3F\uDA7F\uDABF\uDAFF\uDB3F\uDB7F\uDBBF\uDBFF][\uDFFE\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF]/;
```

The responsible grunt build task is the `template`which uses the script `./scripts/export-data.js`. That script contains:

```
'regexInvalidRawCodePoints': require('./invalid-code-points-regex.js'),
```

The `<%= regexInvalidRawCodePoints %>` is a placeholder that will be replace with the content of `./invalid-code-points-regex.js`

This is nothing JavaScript specific, but a placeholder syntax defined by e.g. a template language.

Answer (score 3):

- `regexInvalidRawCodePoint` is a variable
- `/<%= regexInvalidRawCodePoints %>/` is a regular expression (with no options)

<%= and %> are not Javascript.  They are tags that replace `regexInvalidRawCodePoints` with the value of `regexInvalidRawCodePoints` when pre-processing, before the javascript is evaluated.

So the **value** of `regexInvalidRawCodePoint` will be used as the REGEX after it is preprocessed, and that regex will be assigned to the variable `regexInvalidRawCodePoint`